# Common caption under subplots

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

How can i make a common caption in the middle under both plots, which i can reference via a label and how can i remove (a) and (b), so that the subplot captions fit on one line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Compability graph]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) at (0,0) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (B) at (0,1) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (C) at (0,2) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (D) at (2,0) {6};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E) at (2,1) {5};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (F) at (2,2) {4} ;

    \path [-] (C) edge node[left] {} (D);
    \path [-] (C) edge node[left] {} (E);
    \path [-] (C) edge node[left] {} (F);
    \path [-] (B) edge node[left] {} (E);
    \path [-] (B) edge node[left] {} (D);
     \path [-] (A) edge node[left] {} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Conflict graph]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) at (0,0) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (B) at (0,1) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (C) at (0,2) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (D) at (2,0) {6};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E) at (2,1) {5};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (F) at (2,2) {4} ;

    \path [-] (B) edge node[left] {} (F);
    \path [-] (A) edge node[left] {} (E);
     \path [-] (A) edge node[left] {} (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your code so we have a minimal example we can copy-paste-compile. You can use `\caption{}` before `\end{figure}` for the common caption. You would probably find `subcaption` offered you more flexibility than `subfig` concerning the subfloat captions, as you can fully leverage the power of `caption` that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you like to have something like what shows the picture below.

[image]

I like to discourage to do, what you intend. If you will erase the `subcation` number (`(a)`, `(b)`), then you lost ability to referencing them. For one line `subcation` is better a little enlarge horizontal distance as I do in picture above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Compability graph \label{fig:main-a}]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 22mm,
      start chain = going above,
every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw=black, 
    inner sep=1mm, on chain}
                    ]
\node   (A) {3};
\node   (B) {2};
\node   (C) {1};
%
\node   (D) [right=of A]    {6};
\node   (E) {5};
\node   (F) {4} ;
%%
\draw   (C) -- (D)  (C) -- (E)  (C) -- (F)
        (B) -- (E)  (B) -- (D)
        (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Conflict graph \label{fig:main-b}]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 22mm,
      start chain = going above,
every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw=black,
    inner sep=1mm, on chain}
                    ]
\node   (A) {3};
\node   (B) {2};
\node   (C) {1};
%
\node   (D) [right=of A]    {6};
\node   (E) {5};
\node   (F) {4} ;
%%
\draw   (B) -- (F)
        (A) -- (E)  (A) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
}
\caption{Main caption}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, adding main caption is not big deal. Caption facility of `article` put caption on the middle of the text width. If you will use `caption` package, you need to set captions accordingly (for this you need to read package documentation). Otherwise I took a liberty and make your code far more compact, however still stay in pure TikZ picture. In  this I employ libraries `chains` and `positioning`.

Comment: how do you enlarge this?

Comment: I determine distance with `node distance= 3mm and 22mm` in options of TikZ picture. First number is vertical distances between node borders, the second is horizontal. Selected 22 mm seems to be adequate. If this in your real graph, I don't know. However, now it is easy determined distance in one place since, node are positioned relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) - it allows you to specify the width of the box. So, if you specify two boxes each of width `.5\linewidth` they will be centered with respect to the page and each other:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Compability graph}{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-a}%
  }\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Conflict graph}{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-b}%
  }

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{Compability graph}[.5\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-a}%
  }%
  \subcaptionbox{Conflict graph}[.5\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-b}%
  }

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox*{Compability graph}{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-a}%
  }\hfill
  \subcaptionbox*{Conflict graph}{%
    \includegraphics[width=80pt]{example-image-b}%
  }
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It also allows you the option of using the starred `*` version of caption to remove the numbering, giving you a little extra space.